# Resetting root password in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, password

I need to reset my root password. I logged into my Ubuntu installation after a long time and cannot remember that password. I looked at some instructions out [there](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-hack-ubuntu-password/). However instead of 'Press Enter for maintenance', I get 'Give root password for maintenance'. Of course, as I don't have the password I can't get any farther. Please advise.

Comment: Do you have an administrator password that can use `sudo`?

Comment: @fuzzydrawings: Nope. Don't remember sudo password too. Didn't even know that sudo and root passwords were supposed to be different.

Comment: Ubuntu systems should not have a root password in the first place. But this should work: https://askubuntu.com/a/147023/1090451

Answer (score 1):

Use the chroot way to reset the root password:

Boot from Ubutnu live USB/CD.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/chrootdir
```

Mount your root file system (e,g: root=/dev/sda3)

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/chrootdir
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/chrootdir/dev 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/chrootdir/proc
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/chrootdir/dev/pts 
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/chrootdir/sys 
sudo chroot /mnt/chrootdir
```

Then type `passwd` to change the root password.

Exit the chroot, unmount file system, then reboot:

```
exit
sudo umount /mnt/chrootdir/dev
sudo umount /mnt/chrootdir/proc 
sudo umount /mnt/chrootdir/dev/pts 
sudo umount /mnt/chrootdir/sys 
sudo umount /mnt/chrootdir
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? Just boot into single-user mode. During boot, you should see a the grub bootloader where you can select Ubuntu or advanced options for Ubuntu. If it doesn't show up, try hitting shift during boot. (May vary depending on your setup, but this should work for the default.) Now you can edit the boot entry (not permanent, it will go back to the default on next boot) by hitting `e`. Now you can append `init='/bin/bash` at the end of the line saying `linux` (careful, there's line-wrapping so it could also look like it's the next line). Now you'll also have to edit the `ro` in the same line to say `rw`, and boot with the current config by hitting `F10`. You should boot into a bash shell with full rights. Now you can just change the password with `passwd`. After this, rebooting forcefully should be okay, because there are no background jobs. But if you want, you should also be able to use `umount /` to unmount your disk before rebooting forcefully. Now you should boot normally into your system, with a changed password. (careful if you manually added SELinux, then it will be a bit more complicated)

Comment: Here's a nicer explanation for entering single-user mode: https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://gcore.com/learning/how-to-reset-password-in-linux/) there is no need to mount `/proc`, `/dev` and `/sys`:

1. Identify the system partition `/dev/my_partition`:

   ```shell
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```
2. Make a new directory for mounting it:

   ```shell
   sudo mkdir /mnt/my_partition
   ```
3. Mount it:

   ```shell
   sudo mount -v /dev/my_partition /mnt/my_partition
   ```
4. Change root:

   ```shell
   sudo chroot /mnt/my_partition
   ```
5. Reset the root password:

   ```shell
   sudo passwd
   ```

Et voilà!

Comment: This assumes that the OP can use `sudo`.  (They were asked whether they could use `sudo`, and they didn’t answer.)  If they can use `sudo`, why does it need to be so complicated?  — wouldn’t just plain ``sudo passwd`` be enough?