# Login to Linux knowing only the root password

Tags: debian, login, root

I tried top disable the password of my Debian user and must have done something stupid since now I can't login at all anymore with that user.

I do still have the root/sudo password. I tried to type in "root" as the user at the logon screen after the computer boots, but it didn't seem to accept that.

Is there a way to login to my Debian installation knowing only the root account password? Unfortunately I have not enabled SSH on the machine.

Comment: Do you have the root password (the password for the `root` user) or the sudo password (the password for _your_ use who was added to sudoers)?

Comment: @terdon Propably only the sudoers passwords then, I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: Did you try to login to the console ttys, or the GUI?

Comment: The gui (the login screen which eventually loads after booting, similar to Windows logon)

Comment: @user44109 you mean the password you entered when logging in, and every time you ran `sudo`? Then yes, that is your user's password and not root's and you will need to boot from a rescue system as described in [roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704403/22222).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there really is a root password enabled for your installation, then logging with with username `root` and the root password should work. (A `sudo` password is not a root password.) Make sure you're using a full screen "terminal"-style login for this, and not the GUI, because some graphical login managers may prohibit root logins.

If it doesn't, you will need to boot from a rescue system (your Debian installation USB, for example) and follow other instructions to reset or re-enable your user's account through a "`chroot`". For example, this answer for a similar question in Ubuntu, [Resetting root password in Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/686828/100397)